# How to fill a FixedString from string (c++)?

Tags: c++, string

I am trying convert an `std::string` variable to `FixedString`. I really don't understand how to deal with this problem. The code was tested and works ok. I just don't know to convert the variable `std::string test` to `FixedString text`.

---

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

static const int MAX_KEY_LEN = 16;

class FixedString 
{ 
  public:
    char charStr[MAX_KEY_LEN];

    bool operator< (const FixedString& fixedString) const {
        return std::lexicographical_compare(charStr, charStr + MAX_KEY_LEN,
            fixedString.charStr, fixedString.charStr +MAX_KEY_LEN);
    }

    bool operator==(const FixedString& fixedString) const {
        return std::equal(charStr, charStr+MAX_KEY_LEN, fixedString.charStr);
    }

    bool operator!=(const FixedString& fixedString) const {
        return !std::equal(charStr, charStr+MAX_KEY_LEN, fixedString.charStr);
    } 
};

struct comp_type : public std::less<FixedString>
{
    static FixedString max_value()
    {
        FixedString s;
        std::fill(s.charStr, s.charStr+MAX_KEY_LEN, 0x7f);
        return s;
    } 
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   FixedString s;
   string test = "hello";
    //how to convert string test to FixedString test???
   return 0;
}
```

---

Thank you.

Comment: You can use `strcpy()` and `std::string::c_str()`. What's your problem in particular please? Would you mind to improve your question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What about adding an appropriate conversion constructor and assignment operator to your `FixedString` class?

```
 class FixedString 
 { 
 public: 
      char charStr[MAX_KEY_LEN];
      FixedString(const std::string& s)
      {
           // Maybe add some checks and ecxeptions
           strncpy(charStr,s.c_str(),MAX_KEY_LEN);
      }

      FixedString& operator=(const std::string& s)
      {
           // Maybe add some checks and ecxeptions
           strncpy(charStr,s.c_str(),MAX_KEY_LEN);
           return *this;
      }

      // ...
};
```

And use it like

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
   FixedString s1;
   string test1 = "hello";
   s1 = test1; // <<< call overloaded assignment operator

   string test2 = "world";
   FixedString s2(test2); // <<< call overloaded constructor
   return 0;
}
```

[Quickly scribbled demo here](http://ideone.com/x4GPVC)

Comment: Thank you @πάντα ῥεῖ I am testing it. sorry it took so long to answer.

Comment: @HaniGoc See my demo.